# Settings Definition (How to Use On_Change?)

Tags: extension, settings, quickform

Settings definitions allows for a field "on_change". Can anyone explain how to use this? I would like to have it execute a function that I have defined in my extension when my quickform is saved.

THanks!

Documentation Referenced: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/setting/#settings-definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`on_change` is executed when setting value is changed. You can either set it

```
 'on_change' => [
   ['CLASS_NAME', 'functionName'],
 ],
```

Else

```
'on_change' => [
  'CLASS_NAME::functionName',
],
```

A good example would be https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/settings/Localization.setting.php#L145

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Is there any way to pass values through this? Or do I need an API call in my function to get the new value for the setting?

Comment: functionName($oldValue, $newValue, $metadata, $domainID) {}